# Does any US Government agency (like FDA) publish a list of approved food products and ingredients?

Tags: usa, food

For example, consider a category of "bread", it is approved by different Government agencies and are the ingredients specifically included on all products? Do any of these agencies maintain a list of approved products and related data for public use?

Answer (score 5):

The USDA maintains a [National Nutrient Database](http://ndb.nal.usda.gov/) with

> nutrient information on over 8,000 foods using this new and improved
>   search feature. You can now search by food item, group, or list to
>   find the nutrient information for your food items.

The [Nutrient Data Laboratory](http://www.ars.usda.gov/main/site_main.htm?modecode=12-35-45-00) gives food composition and allows you to browse foods *by* nutrient.

FDA 'approval' of food products is somewhat less straight forward- see [What does FDA regulate?](http://www.fda.gov/AboutFDA/Transparency/Basics/ucm194879.htm) section on food.